# variable size datatype(int) in c++

Tags: c++, types

I want to use a datatype to represent sizes like 3bits or 12bits.. can anyone tell me how can I implement this in c++

and is there any code like this, which can help me define size in bits

```
int i:3;
```

thanks in advance ..

Comment: Do you need help with the urge to use data types of 3 or 12 bits? Seriously, if there's a reason not to use byte, short or even int, tell it - because answer depends on it.

Answer (score 3):

you can use structure like this

```
struct Date {
   unsigned short nWeekDay  : 3;    // 0..7   (3 bits)
   unsigned short nMonthDay : 5;    // 0..31  (6 bits)
   unsigned short nMonth    : 4;    // 0..12  (5 bits)
   unsigned short nYear     : 7;    // 0..100 (8 bits)
};
```

Comment: You only need 5 bits for nMonthDay, 4 bits for nMonth and 7 bits for nYear (if you only want to go from 0 to 100).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `vector<bool>` specialization class

```
std::vector<bool> bits(3);
```

or, boost's `dynamic_bitset` class

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<> bits(3);
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html